# How do you recommend not including code with name spaces for older PHP versions

Tags: php

I am distributing a PHP library.  There is an optional component that I'm using that requires namespaces.  If the user of the library does not have a version of PHP >= 5.3.0 I'd like to not include the feature:

Something like what's below (and does not work):

```
 public static function validVisualCaptcha( $formId = NULL, $type = NULL, $fieldName = NULL, $accessibilityFieldName = NULL ) {
            $php_version = phpversion();
            if ($php_version >= '5.3.0') {
               require_once('visualCaptcha/inc/visualcaptcha.class.php'); 

               $visualCaptcha = new \visualCaptcha\Captcha( $formId, $type, $fieldName, $accessibilityFieldName );
              //^^^^^  That Line causes a fatal error if PHP is earlier than 5.3.0
               return $visualCaptcha->isValid();
            }
            else 
                return true;
        }
```

Should I maybe just put that instantiation in its own file and include the file conditionally?  That seems less than elegant.  In C++ I would have used the preprocessor ... I haven't been able to find anything like that in PHP.

Comment: Honestly, if it was me I would refuse to support PHP < 5.3.  Even 5.3 is outside its official support period now (5.4 is considered "old stable"), so that is above and beyond reasonable expectations.

Comment: The real question is: do you really want to maintain code for obsolete en dead php versions?

Comment: "Want to" ... No ...HAVE to ... yes.  This one is outside of my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can get around it (and have it still be valid PHP 5.3 code) is to either move the code to a conditionally loaded `include()`, or to put the conditional code inside an `eval()` call.

The latter is 'evil', but will work fine here:

```
if ($php_version >= '5.3.0') {
    require_once('visualCaptcha/inc/visualcaptcha.class.php'); 

    $visualCaptcha = eval('return new \\visualCaptcha\\Captcha( \$formId, \$type, \$fieldName, \$accessibilityFieldName );');
    return $visualCaptcha->isValid();
}
```

Comment: Don't use eval without sanitizing the variables! Easier and safer is to just conditionally include a file that instantiates and returns the class.

Comment: There are no variables interpolated in the eval. Look again carefully. The contents of the variables has no effect on the evaluated code.